# change timestamp column into hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have this type of timestamp column with type

```
 timestamp        17412 non-null  datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(180)]


timestamp
2021-04-05 00:00:08.776000+03:00
```

how to change into hour minutes second? Also, what is the name of this type of timestamp?

last, what does this means `ns, pytz.FixedOffset(180)`

UPDATE:I remove the  `pytz.FixedOffset(180) by using the following

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_convert(None)
```

OUTPUT:
timestamp
2021-04-04 21:00:08.776

How to round my seconds?

Comment: The name of this type of timestamp is ***datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(180)]***  The meaning of ```ns``` is that the time value measures elapsed nanoseconds, from the epoch,  the meaning of  ```pytz.FixedOffset(180)``` is that the time is referenced to the local timezone which is offset from utc by 180 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.to_datetime(["2018-07-20 09:00:00.055+03:00",
                                                "2020-08-15 18:00:00.056+03:00"])})

# df['timestamp']
# 0   2018-07-20 09:00:00.055000+03:00
# 1   2020-08-15 18:00:00.056000+03:00
# Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(180)]
```

The timestamps have an offset from UTC of +3 hours (180 minutes *ahead* of UTC), that's what the "FixedOffset" tells you.

I'd advise *not to just drop the offset*. Instead, e.g. convert to UTC, `df['timestamp'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')`. Or you can output to string without the UTC offset, `df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`.

If you want to round timestamps down to a certain precision (e.g. seconds), use

```
df['tsfloored'] = df['timestamp'].dt.floor('S')

# df['tsfloored']
# 0   2018-07-20 09:00:00+03:00
# 1   2020-08-15 18:00:00+03:00
# Name: tsfloored, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(180)]
```

See [Offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).